Why can't I retag this question?
The question debug window of wallets needs to be retagged since it has the irrelevant mining-pools tag.  I have 3714 rep but for some reason the "edit tags" button does not appear when I hover.  
I also tried via the "edit" button, which currently says "edit (1)" because there is an edit pending approval.  I get a popup showing me the edit and telling me I have already approved it (which I have), but no apparent way to make further edits.
Other questions seem to work normally.

I think I encountered this problem previously as well: If you approve an edit, but it needs more approvals before the edit review is completed you cannot make any further changes. If you see a mistake just after you approved the edit, you are out of luck. ;)
Apparently there is no mid-ground between, choosing to improve the edit immediately, and waiting for the edit review to complete.
I believe it should be possible for you to edit now, as the suggested edit has been processed?

When a post has a pending suggested edit (an edit by an anonymous user or one without edit privileges), it needs to be approved before further edits can be made to the post.
This includes retags, as they are classed as edits to the post.
